# Is it true Wynantskill, NY has a real problem with aircraft noise from Air Force, or other aircrafts? Thank you

Tags: noise

Is it true Wynantskill, NY has a real problem with aircraft noise from Air Force, or other aircraft? Looking to buy a home, but do not want this problem I may have heard on NPR. Thank you.

Comment: Define "problem"...  For some it's the sound of freedom!

Comment: Local zoning authorities may have actual measured data on that, if the area is considered to be a high risk area for aircraft (or any other) noise.

Comment: Performing a quick Google search resulted in numerous complaints about dogs barking and atv use (both during the daytime, no less!) but nothing about aircraft. And IIRC the one I saw about ATV's was named Karen... for real.

Answer (score 3):

The nearest military air operations to Wynantskill would be the Air National Guard operation out of [Schenectady County Airport - KSCH](http://www.airnav.com/airport/ksch). Neither runway lends to an approach or departure in the direction of Wynantskill and all the instrument approaches are more or less West of the ALB VOR. [There are no MOAs](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pham_html/chap25_section_1.html) or Restricted airspace that overly that area directly. Thus there is no reason to believe military overflight is any more of a nuisance there than it would be anywhere else. [This NYS site offers some reassuring info on that front](https://dmna.ny.gov/community/adk_aircraft/) (bolded for emphasis):

> While high-performance military aircraft **train over northern New York**,
> the **New York Air National Guard does not operate aircraft that may
> generate high noise levels or sonic booms**.